# SonarQube claims condition to always evaluate to false for fields accessed with "this."

Tags: java, sonarqube

This seems to be a new example of a false positive of the rule "Conditionally executed blocks should be reachable" ([squid:S2583](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2583)). Does anyone know why SonarQube claims that `if(this.x == 0)` always evaluates to `false` in the following Java class?

```
public class MyClass {

    private long x;

    void setX(long x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void decrementX() {
        if(this.x > 0) {
            this.x--;
            if(this.x == 0)  { //                 <-- Always false?!
                // apparently dead code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly the variable `x` can be set to `1` and then `decrementX()` will get into that exact condition:

```
@Test
public void testDecrement() {
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    c.setX(1);
    c.decrementX();
}
```

(executed on SonarQube server 5.6.6 with SonarJava plugin 4.13.0.11627)

**Update**: as noted by Absurd-Mind, SonarQube is happy when `this.x` is shortened to `x`. In my opinion, this is a false-positive.

Comment: This shouldn't have impact, but do you get the same result when removing the `this.`?

Comment: I tried it without the `this.` and that really makes the difference! Only absurd minds would think of this....

Comment: That sounds like a bug then. You should consider filing a bug at https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel Post a link to your bugticket as an answer and put also the update 'removing this.' in the answer. That would really help others and would give you an update :)

Comment: I thought so, but don't seem to have rights to create new issues directly in sonarsource's JIRA. On their website they even suggest reporting bugs to google groops or stackoverflow...

Comment: You won't be able to open a ticket in our JIRA, which has restricted access. We monitor both channels (our mailing list and SOF), so opening a question here is fine. I'm investigating the issue and what is currently happening in our Symbolic Execution engine. I'm going to answer with a proper JIRA ticket and explanation once investigated, but this is definitely a FP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a False Positive (FP) raised by version 4.13.0.11627 of the SonarJava plugin.

After investigation, the FP is caused by a bug in handling of unary operators in our Symbolic Execution (SE) engine. The following ticket will fix the issue: [SONARJAVA-2460](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2460) (expected fix version: 4.14)

For details about WHY the issue is occurring: Class fields, when accessed using `this.x` or `super.x`, are not handled as they should be. They are currently purely and simply ignored (will be fixed by the JIRA ticket). It has for side effect that update of the field occurring with `this.x--` is not registered by the SE engine: the symbolic value associated to symbol `x` is not updated. Consequently, when test `x == 0` is done, the only thing that the engine knows at this time is the (wrong) constraint that `x > 0`. In such state, the condition will always be false. Fixing the issue will allow the engine to know that the `x` tested in the condition is not the same anymore as the one used for checking `x > 0`.